# React and Webpack Issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, error-handling, compiler-errors

I have started to build a React App and implemented 3 pages which worked fine.
After structuring the first page, my app crashed and I am not able to restart it since.

I don´t know if it has something to do with it but I use Redux as well.

I tried without the page I created cause I thought maybe I messed up there. But nothing changed. I even rebuilt my app 2 times now without any changes.

Following errors occur:

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpKhT.jpg)

Folders:

[My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahEWD.png)

Package.json

[My package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVLql.png)

However, the backend is running perfectly fine. Issue is just on the frontend.
I tried multiple tutorials how to fix this but nothing worked

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Can you show your frontend code ? 
Do you import backend code inside frontend code ?

Comment: The issue is not related to redux at all I think